# python with statment finally

Tags: python, with-statement

I miss `finally` for `with`. I would like to do something like this:

(NOT working code!)

```
with open(path, 'w') as f:
   doing_something(f)
finally:
   do_something_else()
```

so I want `do_something_else` when an exception happens. The file will be closed properly, `with` takes care of that, but I have other tasks to do on error. What I would expect from python to allow a syntax like this above as `with` already has a non visible `finally` statement, I just would like to add some calls there.

But currently I can write only this:

(Working, but not nice code)

```
try:
   with open(path, 'w') as f:
      doing_something(f)
finally:
   do_something_else()
```

What is the nicer way of doing this?

Comment: I'd start looking into implementing my own context manager that does your file open() - see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html

Comment: The with block doesn't have an implicit finally, the file object has an `__exit__` method. If you were really opposed to the try/except approach you could write a custom context manager and do something like `with (open('file') as f, other_context()): ...` using the [nested contexts in python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#parenthesized-context-managers) but it'd make it difficult for anyone else reading your code.

Comment: Since the `with` statement (context manager) is internally working like a `try-except-finally` I would either expect your `doing_something()` method to return an error code (or a binary `true/false` and based on that result execute `do_something_else()`

Comment: This is how exceptions are handled that are propagated up to your code. The fact that the context manager can handle some exceptions does not change that. You are just given the option to write your own context manager.